# How to ignore Git subtree from parent project

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-subtree

I am using `git subtree` for my personal website, where I code in dev branch and it's `build`/`make` produces `dist` directory which is what I want to publish and is hence to master branch.

In short:

- **Dev**: code(with dist)
- **Master**: dist(published to git pages)

Now, I want to push code to dev and be able to ignore dist directory in it and my subtree to still work fine. I tried putting "dist" in `.gitignore` file but it seems to be not working, may be because it's linked to a subtree. Is it achievable, how?

For reference here is [link to my Github repo](https://github.com/92arpitgoyal/92arpitgoyal.github.io) of the project.

Comment: How can git ignore something that's already being tracked?

Comment: These are two different branches and dist is supposed to track only for master branch not dev. I am not sure if and how it is possible, hence the question.